# How to test this method right?(junit)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

I have this method :

```
@Transactional
@Service("vacancyService")
public class VacancyService {

   public boolean delete(Integer id) {
        Vacancy vacancy = vacancyDao.findById(id);
        return vacancy != null && vacancyDao.remove(vacancy);
    }
  ...
}
```

I want to test above method.

realization  `vacancyDao.remove(vacancy)`:

```
  public boolean remove(Vacancy vacancy) throws HibernateException {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            if (vacancy == null) {
                return false;
            }

            int result = session.createQuery("delete from Vacancy where id = :id")
                    .setInteger("id", vacancy.getId()).executeUpdate();
            return result > 0;

        }
```

My test class:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
public class VacancyServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @Test
    public void testDeleteMethod(){
        //what I can write here?
    }
```

I have no idea how to test this method. Can you help me?

**UPDATE**

add here my configuration files:

BeanConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Включаем опцию использования конфигурационных аннотаций (@Annotation-based configuration)-->
    <context:annotation-config />


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.jpa" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.services" />

    <!-- Файл с настройками ресурсов для работы с данными (Data Access Resources) -->
    <import resource="data.xml" />

</beans>
```

data.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.16.9.52:1433;databaseName=hhsystemTest;"
        p:username="userNew" 
        p:password="Pass12345" />

    <!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:test/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

If you need more details I post it here.

Comment: Please post your `BeanConfig.xml`.

Comment: Are we talking about unit testing the delete method?  If so, have you considered stubbing/mocking your `VacancyDao` class?

Comment: no, I want test full method

Answer (score 2):

Since service class unit tests are provided, Here is the way to unit test your Dao class remove method

```
public class vacancyDaoTest {

@InjectMocks
VacancyDao vacancyDao = new VacancyDao();

@Mock
Session session;

@Mock
Query query;

@Mock
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@BeforeClass
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(sessionFactory.getSession()).thenReturn(session);
}



@Test
public void testRemove(){
    String hql = "delete from Vacancy where id = :id";
    when(session.createQuery(hql)).thenReturn(query);
    when(query.setInteger(eq("id"), anyInt())).thenReturn(query);
    when(query.executeUpdate).thenReturn(1);
    int result = vacancyDao.remove(new Vacancy());
    verify(session).createQuery(any(String.class));
    verify(query).setInteger(eq("id"), anyInt());
    verify(query).executeUpdate();
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertTure(result);


}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it a unit test rather than an integration test I would remove the spring test annotations altogether and "inject" a mock service through a mock object framework like [Mockito](http://mockito.googlecode.com).  And then you would need several simple unit tests to cover the several conditions.  I would save integration testing for the DAO layer.

As a first cut (with Mockito static imports omitted):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnit4Runner.class)
public class VacancyServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @InjectMocks private VacancyService vacancyService;
    @Mock private VacancyDAO vacancyDao;

    @Mock Vacancy vacancy;

    @Test
    public void testDeleteMethod_notFound(){
        when(vacancyDao.findById(10).thenReturn(null);

        assertFalse(vacancyService.delete(10));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteMethod_foundButRemoveFailed(){
        when(vacancyDao.findById(10).thenReturn(mock(Vacancy.class));
        when(vacancyDao.remove(vacancy).thenReturn(false);

        assertFalse(vacancyService.delete(10));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteMethod_success(){
        when(vacancyDao.findById(10).thenReturn(mock(Vacancy.class));
        when(vacancyDao.remove(vacancy).thenReturn(true);

        assertTrue(vacancyService.delete(10));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Create Vacancy object,
Query it by Id, it should return value.
Then delete it, 
Then query for id, if id does not exist your test should pass.

But this will not be pure Unit test, as it assumes "Create" and "Query by id" working fine, and if they have errors, this test will fails also,

You can use Assume Tag in JUnit, to make sure that this test is independent from create and query by id.

Another Option would be using unitils with DBUnit, check : http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Write your test class as this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:BeanConfig.xml",
        "classpath:data.xml" })
// This annotation is needed because the configuration does not support creation
// of non-transactional session.
@Transactional
public class VacancyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    VacancyService serviceUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(serviceUnderTest.delete(1));
    }

}
```

By default, the framework will create and roll back a transaction for each test. Even if a test method deletes the contents of selected tables while running within the transaction managed for the test, the transaction will roll back by default, and the database will return to its state prior to execution of the test.

Comment: I want to test, that if after execution this method if I invoke findById I get null

Comment: You want to test `vacancyDao.findById` or `VacancyService.delete`?

Comment: I want to be sure that after execution of this method this object doesn't exist in database

Comment: The test method `public void test()` that I have written in my answer, has `assertTrue(serviceUnderTest.delete(1))`. Assuming your `vacancyDao.remove(vacancy)` returns `true` on successful deletion of record, the `assertTrue` test will pass successfully if the object got deleted from DB, otherwise it will fail. Because `vacancyDao.remove(vacancy)` will return `false` if it could not delete DB record and we are expecting the result to be `true`.